# How can I filter a windowing function for the max row number?

Tags: sql-server, windowing

I am trying to get the max row in a partitioned result. How can I get the max row for each return where I partition by property number. What I want are the rows that are marked by 2 because that is the last value in the set. If the property number doesn't have a subsequent number then I want that one (red arrow).

The following is a picture of my result.

Currently, I'm making a temp table and a do a group by on the property number and the max(row) and then use this to then filter this set of data.

I'm sure there may be a better way without wasting too much temp space. [image]

Comment: can you show the whole query you executed?

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY ROW 
                    ORDER BY PropertyNumber DESC) AS Rownumber
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: It's `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)`

Comment: @ypercube Sorry, fixed now